# How to convert HTML content to PDF in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, pdf, xamarin, xamarin.forms, html-to-pdf

I want to convert HTML content to PDF. I have tried using third party API like GemBox, GrapeCity..
these all are working in UWP but in android failing.

Please suggest any solution. I can go with paid API's also.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe if you provided some details about "in android failing" we could help you fix it?

Comment: @Jason I am getting this issue with GemBox.Document API. But 
 I am not using this font-Faimly in html. System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot get a matching glyph typeface for font 'Times New Roman'.'

Comment: 'Times New Roman' is the default font in HTML, so it seems that some content is getting a default font? Anyway, without investigating your HTML it's hard to say, but nevertheless, to create PDF file you will need to have font files on the android. There are three ways how you can provide fonts: installed, private, or embedded.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a one-in-all solution, you can check out the leadtools document converter nuget here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Leadtools.Document.Sdk/ disclaimer: i am employed by the vendor of this library

LEADTOOLS supports HTML -> PDF as well as a bunch of other formats. You can see more information here: https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/document/document-converter

This library supports Xamarin on Android, UWP, and iOS and is completely offline.

Here is a snippet of code that will work for your use-case:

```
using (var documentConverter = new DocumentConverter())
{
   var htmlString = File.ReadAllText(@"./test.htm");
   using (var ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(htmlString)))
   {
      var htmlDocument = DocumentFactory.LoadFromStream(ms, new LoadDocumentOptions());
      var jobData = DocumentConverterJobs.CreateJobData(htmlDocument, "output.pdf", DocumentFormat.Pdf);
      var job = documentConverter.Jobs.CreateJob(jobData);
      documentConverter.Jobs.RunJob(job);
   }
}
```

Comment: will it work if I pass html content as string instead of "./input.html". Actually I want to pass html content as string.

Comment: Yes, you can get a memorystream from the bytes and then load that. I updated my answer to show how.